# Acessing textutil source code

Tags: macos

Is it possible open the source code of the textutil command-line utility?

I'm not finding anything in google.

Thanks.

Comment: is it found in `OSX`?

Comment: Yes @Serge, it is.

Comment: Then the question is hardly linux-related and most likely the utility is not open sourced. At least I can't recall such utility in relation to linux family.

Comment: Yeap, you are right.. is a MACOSX feature. Sorry, i will update my question.

Comment: I've done a moderate search and not been able to find the source code, either separate from Mac OS X or in the https://opensource.apple.com/ repository.  I'm not certain that it isn't available, but I don't plan to spend more time looking for it.